# how do I go from typing `/foo` to `:%s/foo/bar` efficiently

Tags: vim, vi

In `vim`, I typed `/foo` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and found some matches.

Now I want to replace all instances of `foo` with `bar` (i.e. `:%s/foo/bar`).

Can this be done without retyping the `foo`?  (e.g. into the command line following `:`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `:%s//bar`.

Explanation: in the substitute command when the search pattern is empty, Vim uses the last search pattern.

Alternatively, you can explicitly paste the last search pattern, which is stored in a special register. You can quickly insert its contents by typing <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in insert or command mode.

So enter command mode, type `%s/`, then <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to paste the last pattern, and then the remaining `/bar`.